# How to convert Avro file to CSV file in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, bigdata

The process I am following is -

1. Converting Avro to JSON
2. Then converting JSON to CSV

Is there any direct way to convert the Avro file to CSV?

Comment: Sure, you can parse Avro in Python... Whatever you do with it afterwards is an implementation detail

Answer (score 8):

This is how I converted an avro file to csv:

```
from fastavro import reader
import csv

head = True
count = 0
f = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w+"))
with open('abc.avro', 'rb') as fo:
    avro_reader = reader(fo)
    for emp in avro_reader:
        #print(emp)
        if head == True:
            header = emp.keys()
            f.writerow(header)
            head = False
        count += 1
        f.writerow(emp.values())
print(count)
```

Comment: Do you need to close the csv file?  I may or may not have a list of avro files....